# radio button syntax with jquery handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to use the equation syntax javascript jquery for this syntax:

```
document.getElementById ("tone_positive_" + x). checked = true
```

some examples I have tried but failed or did I not understand the radio buttons to cope with jquery, thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't

```
$("#tone_positive_" + x).attr("checked", "checked");
```

work?

Comment: I'm french but it's not what I understand reading his question.

Comment: @Philemon It looks like he's trying to do it with just JavaScript but he mentions jQuery in his question too.